# Logging login events on my Windows 7 desktop OS to a file

Tags: authentication

I suspect someone is login into my computer when I check event viewer. Is it possible to have a script on windows 7 to record every login onto my windows 7 desktop pc?

Answer (score 2):

Windows already can do this using the [MMC module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console). 
 But if you do not trust it, you can add an autorun to your profiles that does this 'logging'

Answer (score 1):

## Try WinLogOnView

Windows already logs this into the security log.

There is a nice freeware GUI: NirSofts's [WinLogOnView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_log_on_times_view.html)

Comment: why use a 3rd party app when the MMC enables you to see this already?

Comment: Because the security log has too much throughput. It is unreadable to me. Even on my single user machine. There are currently 21k events. (~20MB) WinLogonView parses this into just 105 sessions. And it also calculates session duration. (Which eventvwr.msc does not, I think.)

Comment: Learn to use the filters, instead of relying on external tools that you have no knowledge about how it works , or what data it sends to 3rd party (or worse what security holes it opens)

Comment: Sure. But the [VirusTotal report of my WinLogonView.exe is clean](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/980b7ed2a5b44e3cb2031680c7a21c4bdc89e0689e4dd19193793a7b787afea8/analysis/1429685964/). And NirSoft has been around for long enough for me to trust them. Worth the risk to me.